How to encode/decode complex conditions into 256 bit
I'd like to encode conditions in a single 256 bit integer to avoid storage costs.
For example, assume that user passes 4 addresses(address[] type) to my smart contract function and he also wants to pass the encode of those addresses in a logical operator approach. For example, let's assume that we have addr1, addr2, addr3, addr4 and he wants to pass me something like:
(addr1 or addr2) and (addr3 or addr4)
This is useful because in my business logic, these addresses at some point call my contract and I need to know when I can 100% say that the goal(condition) has been achieved. Note that some of them mightn't even call my contract for several reasons as well. So if let's say, add2 and addr1 call it, then that means the goal hasn't been achieved, but if addr2 and addr3 called it, the goal was achieved.
Problem is that the number of addresses can be anything and conditions can also be anything. I need to be able to encode these conditions in a UI, then store it in smart contract in 256 bit and at each time, address calls my contract, I need to check whether
the goal has been achieved. Because of this, I also should be able to decode this from 256 bit integer to the actual conditions so I can check it.
I thought to pass conditions as indexes of the address array. In the above example, that would be as: (0 or 1) and (2 or 3) but even that, how do I encode and then decode. Thank you for your time.

I don't understand what do you mean by the logical operator approach. What does it represent (addr1 or addr2) and (addr3 or addr4)? Solidity isn't a suitable language to encode/decode arbitrary data. It could be done using bytes array, but you have to do most of the work by hand. If you look around there are some libraries that provide RLP encoding for example https://github.com/Maia-DAO/solidity-rlp-encoder, but perhaps they are too simple or not well suited for your project in particular.
